# Firefox Jetpack Development Debugging

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

So, I'm working with some JS in Firefox and also working with the jetpack sdk. I am working in a JS editor, and then I run the sdk through the command line. However, when there is a bug there is no way to debug this because the JS is being run/loaded before the page and the DOM so firebug is to no avail.

Can anyone recommend a better tool for this? It is quite tedious "making educated guesses" about where errors are starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out the JavaScript debugger [Venkman](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/venkman/).

It's slightly more powerful than the debugger provided by FireBug.

Here's the [Venkman Walkthrough](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/venkman/venkman-walkthrough.html) which covers the basics. Not sure why they don't link to it from the front page...go figure.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to install Venkman or Firebug anymore, just use the built in debugger.

> On Firefox 19 or later, it's possible to use the built-in JS debugger on the browser itself.  Go to about:config and set the following two prefs:
>
> `devtools.chrome.enabled: true`
>
> `devtools.debugger.remote-enabled: true`
>
> After you restart the browser, the Web Developer menu will contain a "Browser Debugger" entry.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_JavaScript)